# Inserting svg-files as foreignObject, in to SVG embedded to DOM as <оbject>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

i have got SVG-file embedded to DOM as *<оbject>*.

```
<object id="motor" type="image/svg+xml"
    data="img/motor.svg"  width="119.055mm" height="119.055mm">
</object>
```

Inside svg-object, i had defined **container** (*g*-tag) for (in future) inserting other SVG-images from selected svg-files.
Container:

```
<g id="shape35-26" transform="translate(31.1811,-48.189)" data-id="MainSwitch">
  <rect x="0" y="102.047" width="17.0079" height="17.0079" class="st3"/>
  //from rect-tag i will read the container sizes
</g>
```

I read selected svg-files by XMLHttpRequest, after that i have two definition of results:

1. string with svg-file content `<svg  ... </svg>` (from XMLHttpRequest.responseTex)
2. document-object ( resul of:

```html
var parser = new DOMParser();
var stringContainingXMLSource = s;
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "image/svg+xml");
```

)

How can i create and insert foreignObject (with svg-file) to **container**?

Answer (score 0):

No foreignObject is needed. `<svg>` elements can be nested.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var stringContainingXMLSource = s;
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "image/svg+xml");
var svg = doc.querySelector('svg');

// select the <object> content document
const objectDoc = document.querySelector('#motor').contentDocument;

// select the insertion group
const mainSwitch = objectDoc.querySelector('[data-id="MainSwitch"]');

// get the bounding box of the <rect>
const box = mainSwitch.querySelector('rect').getBBox();
// set all of them on the svg to insert
svg.setAttribute('x', box.x);
svg.setAttribute('y', box.y);
svg.setAttribute('width', box.width);
svg.setAttribute('height', box.height);

// now insert into the object DOM
mainSwitch.appendChild(svg);
```

This will not work as expected if the SVG to insert is missing its viewBox attribute. It would be best to make sure it exists on all files.